# Session value only updating after page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am setting session value on menu click via ajax and ajax returning correct response. But after page load it shows old value and always require page reload to get correct and updated value. Actually i want to get clicked menu element id on the next page.
Here is my ajax code

```
jQuery('.menu .menu-item').click(function(event){
var menu = jQuery(this).attr('id');
var url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data: {
               action: 'review_vote_ajax_request',
               menu: menu
           },
            success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
            }
       }); 
});
```

Here is my php code

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_review_vote_ajax_request', 'review_vote_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_review_vote_ajax_request', 'review_vote_ajax_request' );
function review_vote_ajax_request() {
$menu = $_REQUEST['menu'];
echo $menu;
session_start();  
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $menu;
wp_die();
}
```

Then on page load i am trying to get session value but it shows old value and always require page reload to get updated value.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['myvar'])) {
$value = $_SESSION['myvar'];
echo $value;
}
```

Is there any way so that i can get updated value from session on page load for first time?
I ll just need little guidance about this process.
 Your help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information about how to ask a question in a format expected for stack overflow.

Comment: Question is hard to understand.  Can you post some sample code that illustrates what you are doing, what you want to happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I update my code but as i was working in WordPress CMS and everything was working perfectly and only the problem was to get updated value that is why i did not add my code. Thank you for your time.