# Page reload once before loading any of the other content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload my site (only once) before loading any of the content. I implemented this option but the user is still able to see the content of the page before going for reload.
Here is my code

```
window.onload = function() {
if(!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
}
```

}

How can I implement this functionality without showing any of the content to the site visitor.

Comment: what do you mean by **any of the other content**

Comment: My site visitor always able to see page before reload and i do not want to show this before reload.

Comment: Whats the point of slowing down your website with reload?

Comment: I am not worried about slowing down site. I just want to hide page content from visitor and only want to display second time (after reload).

Comment: What is the goal ?

Comment: @pirs my goal is just to hide content from viewer so he could not see any thing and only will be able to see page after reload.

Comment: Why reload so ??

Comment: I am trying to fetch some info from sessions. First time i could not access these info so that is why i want to implement reload.

Comment: Here is my initial issue that i am trying to resolve with reload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100981/session-value-only-updating-after-page-reload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you don't want your user to see any of the content on the page before you trigger the reload?

If you mean 'see', like visually see the content, you could always put a div that blocks the entire viewport, and then remove it once the page has been reloaded.

But to me, this seems like an issue that could be resolved by not adding anything to the document body until your conditions have been met. You should design your code in such a way that a refresh is not needed, as that is creating unnecessary requests.